# Multiplication of negative numbers is always positive

Tags: number-systems

Show that Multiplication of negative numbers is always positive eg. (-1)*(-1)=1

Comment: are you allowed $-1 \cdot -1 = 1$ as a given?

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304422/formal-proof-for-1-times-1-1

Answer (score 0):

Define for any number $a$ the opposite of $a$ the unique number $-a$ such that 
$a+(-a)=0$.  As $-a=a-2a=-1\cdot a$ the opposite of $a$ is achieved by multiplication of $a$ by $-1$.  Hence 
$$-1\cdot (-1)= \text{opposite of $(-1)$}=\text{the unique number that adds up $-1$ to $0$}=1.$$