# Significance of multiplying $-1$ by $-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Maybe this is a weird question but it's been bugging me.

In the childhood we were taught that $4 \times 3$ means $4+4+4$ i.e. adding 4, 3 times.

My question is then how would you explain $-1 \times -1$ using some kind of mathematical logic?
I want to know the significance in real life.

It doesn't have a meaning when I say adding $-1$, $-1$ times.

Comment: In a sense, it *does* have a meaning of "adding $-1$, $-1$ times". Because adding something $-1$ times is the same as *taking away* something $1$ time.

So you start with nothing, and you *take away* the value $-1$, you are left with $1$.

Comment: @5xum: I think you should post that as an answer - it is very well explained!

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/why-is-negative-times-negative-positive, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64488/if-multiplication-is-not-repeated-addition, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304422/formal-proof-for-1-times-1-1

Comment: When we grow up we [taught](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&q=Theorem+1.2.+Let+R+be+a+ring.#v=snippet&q=Theorem%201.2.%20Let%20R%20be%20a%20ring.&f=false) : (-a)b= -(ab)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at it this way,

$3 \times 4$ , you have a defined credit of $3$ and you gain $4$ times as much as that credit:

$$(+3+3+3+3) = (+12)$$

$3 \times -4$ , here you have a defined credit but you lose $4$ times as much of that credit:

$$(-3-3-3-3) = (-12)$$

$-3 \times 4$ , you have a debt of $-3$ and you gain 4 times as much debt as that debt:

$$[+(-3)+(-3)+(-3)+(-3)] = (-3-3-3-3) = (-12)$$

$-3 \times -4$ , define a debt of $-3$ and lose 4 times of that debt, which means you gain credit by losing the debt:

$$[-(-3)-(-3)-(-3)-(-3)] = (+3+3+3+3) = (+12)$$

> Here is a nice little video about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij-EK-MZv2Q) topic:
>
> At [$11$:$38$](https://youtu.be/ij-EK-MZv2Q?t=698) He explains the same thing I've just written.

Comment: Thanks for the real life significance. I needed that one

Answer (score 4):

We can also reason from the ring axioms. Not quite so intuitive, but this is the core reason that $-1\cdot -1=1$, so I feel like for completeness' sake, it should be included. We'll quickly do a couple of lemma's that it follows from:

> **Lemma.** We have $-(-a)=a$.

*Proof*. We know \begin{align}
a&=a+0\\
&=a+((-a)+-(-a))\\
&=(a+(-a))+-(-a)\\
&=0+-(-a)\\
&=-(-a)
\end{align}

> **Another lemma.** We have $0\cdot a=0$.

*Proof.* We know \begin{align}
a\cdot 0&=a\cdot 0+0\\
&=a\cdot 0+((a\cdot0+-(a\cdot 0))\\
&=((a\cdot 0)+(a\cdot0))+-(a\cdot 0)\\
&=a\cdot(0+0)+-(a\cdot 0)\\
&=a\cdot0+-(a\cdot 0)\\
&=0
\end{align}
(This proof can also be tweaked to have $a\cdot0=0=0\cdot a$ in non-commutative rings)

> **Last lemma.** We have $-a=a\cdot -1$.

*Proof.* We know \begin{align}
-a&=-a+0\\
&=-a+(a\cdot 0)\\
&=-a+(a\cdot (1+-1))\\
&=-a+((a\cdot1)+(a\cdot-1))\\
&=(-a+(a\cdot1))+(a\cdot-1)\\
&=(-a+a)+(a\cdot-1)\\
&=0+(a\cdot-1)\\
&=a\cdot-1
\end{align}
Now it follows that $-1\cdot -1=-(-1)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I've often seen this proof/explaination
$$\bigg(ab + (-a)b\bigg) + (-a)(-b) = \bigg(ab + (-a)b\bigg) + (-a)(-b)$$
$$\bigg(ab + (-a)b\bigg) + (-a)(-b) = ab + \bigg((-a)b + (-a)(-b)\bigg)$$
$$\bigg(a+(-a)\bigg)b+(-a)(-b) =ab +\bigg(b+(-b)\bigg)(-a)$$
$$0b+(-a)(-b) =ab +0(-a)$$
$$0+(-a)(-b) =ab +0$$
$$(-a)(-b) =ab$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting question and much deeper than it seems to be when it occurs in a non-commutative setting. But let us come back to children. One possible way to justify the product by $-1$ is to rely on distributivity.
Actually, saying that $4 \times 3$ means $4 + 4 + 4$ amounts to define $3$ as $1 + 1 + 1$ and then use 
$$
4 \times (1 + 1 + 1) = (4 \times 1) + (4 \times 1) + (4 \times 1).
$$
Then of course one also needs $4 \times 1 = 4$ to fully justify this approach.
Now, suppose you want to give a meaning to $4 \times (-2)$ while keeping distributivity. You may observe that 
$$
(4 \times 2) + (4 \times (-2)) = 4 \times (2 + (-2)) = 4 \times 0 = 0.
$$
Again, one needs to know that $4 \times 0 = 0$, but children should buy that easily.
Anyway, now, the only possibility is to have $4 \times (-2) = - (4 \times 2)$. Last step, $(-4) \times (-2)$. Requiring distributivity forces the equality
$$
  ((-4) \times (-2)) + 4 \times (-2) = (4 + (-4)) \times (-2) = 0 \times (-2) = - (0 \times 2) = - 0 = 0
$$
And finally, yes, $(-1) \times (-1) = 1$ !

Answer (score 1):

In the XVIII century, an outstanding scientist, mathematician and engineer Leonhard Euler explained generally multiplying negative numbers like this. Clearly,$-5 \cdot 4 =-20.$ Therefore, the product $-5 \cdot (-4)$ can not be equal $-20$, but the product has to be somehow related with the number $20$. There remains only one possibility: $-5 \cdot (-4)= 20$

Therefore $-1 \cdot (-1)=1$