# Significance of parenthesis around a negative number in proofs

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was going through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304426) answer.

Why we need to generate `1+(-1)` from `1-1`.

What is the significance of bringing a parenthesis `()` around `-1`.

I am new to proofs . Sorry for poor math terminology.

Answer (score 2):

When working with fields, the meaning of $a-b$ is $a+(-b)$. In particular, $1-1$ means $1+(-1)$, that is, the sum of the numbers $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

> `1+(-1)`
>
> What is the significance of bringing a parenthesis around `-1`?

Disambiguation and readibility. $\;$`1+-1`$\;$ isn't ambiguous; however, does $\;$`1+-1+3`$\;$ mean $$1+(-1+3)$$ or $$1+(-1)+3?$$

P.S. In each of these two expressions, the first minus sign is a binary operation, whereas the second minus sign is a unary operation: $$1--3\\1-(-3)$$